# Zend Db Table Abstract add new field to the row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I once posted this question, but had no answer at all, this time, the question is best formated so It will be more easy to understand what I need.

I created a Model with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Add the primaryKey and the table name, all ok.

Then, I executed the code to retrieve the fonts.

```
$db = new App_Model_News();

$news = $db->fetchAll("visible = 1", "published_on DESC");

foreach ($news as $i => $new) {

    $images = $this->_helper->News->first_image($new);

}
```

This method works, but I need to retrieve two view statements:

```
$this->view->news = $news;
$this->view->images = $images;
```

What I need is to merge this two results, doing something like this.

```
$db = new App_Model_News();

$news = $db->fetchAll("visible = 1", "published_on DESC");

foreach ($news as $i => $new) {

    $news[$i]->images = $this->_helper->News->first_image($new);

}
$this->view->news = $news;
```

I'm not able to do it, because the Abstract is array associative, my Model is like this:

```
class App_Model_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

    protected $_name = 'news';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

    protected $_dependentTables = array('ImagesNews');

}

class ImagesNews extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

    protected $_name = 'news_imagens';
    protected $_primary = 'id_new';

    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'Arquivos' => array(
            'columns'           => 'id_new',
            'refTableClass'     => 'App_Model_News',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        ));    
}
```

Is there any way to add the images inside the news rows? Then at the view I could loop and print the images.

Thanks and best regard's.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you could do is to create your own custom News row class:

```
class App_Model_Row_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
     public $images;
}
```

Then you would tell App_Model_News to use the custom row class:

```
class App_Model_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

    protected $_name = 'news';
    protected $_primary = 'id';
    protected $_rowClass = 'App_Model_Row_News';

    protected $_dependentTables = array('ImagesNews');

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin! Helped a lot.

Comment: In other words, use Doctrine :D